# Can you combine multiple expressions for an Azure pipeline stage?

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines

With Azure pipelines you can set conditions for stage or job execution using [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops).

```
  displayName: Release Build
  dependsOn:
    - Testing
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
```

Can you combine `xor` and `and` [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions) into a compound expression? I have the following expression but it evaluates to false every time. So I am either  misinterpreting it or have not formatted it correctly. My understanding is that one of the succeeded clauses in the `xor` has to be true and that the build reason is *not* a `pull request` for the overall expression to evaluate to `true`, is this correct?

Otherwise the mistake must be unrelated to the condition ‍♂️

```
and(xor(succeeded('Ad_Hoc_Build'), succeeded('release_build')), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

Comment: In my case the  stage names had changed and the run failed silently ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, you can chain them. if both expressions in xor() are true or false at the same time it would return false - meaning your condition will never succeed